# How to access interface fields on json decode?

Tags: json, go

I have a json document and I'm using a client which decodes the document in an interface (instead of struct)  as below:

```
var jsonR interface{}
err = json.Unmarshal(res, &jsonR)
```

How can I access the interface fields? I've read the go doc and [blog](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go) but my head still can't get it. Their example seem to show only that you can decode the json in an interface but doesn't explain how its fields can be used.

I've tried to use a range loop but it seems the story ends when I reach a map[string]interface. The fields that I need seem to be in the interface.

```
for k, v := range jsonR {
    if k == "topfield" {
        fmt.Printf("k  is %v, v is %v", k, v)

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question? It's hard to tell exactly what you want to know.

Comment: You can use json.RawMessage to implements delay JSON decoding.    http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage

Answer (score 0):

The value inside the interface depends on the json structure you're parsing. If you have a json dictionary, the dynamic type of `jsonR` will be: `map[string]interface{}`.

Here's an example.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    a := []byte(`{"topfield": 123}`)
    var v interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(a, &v); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unmarshal failed: %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("value is %v", v.(map[string]interface{})["topfield"])
}
```

Comment: Printing the topfield  I get something as below this which seems to be the interface itself. How can I access the obj value ? [map[_geoloc:map[fl:51 lg:33233] _tg:[xmaM] obj:FXX00X _hhg:map[mgs:[map[value:xmaMKA lcv:none mwo:[]]]]]]

Comment: You need to use another [type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to turn `v["topfield"]` into a map or list you can do another lookup in, and repeat at each level: `v.(map[string]interface{})["topfield"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["__geoloc"].(map[string]interface{})["fl"]` to get what would be `v.topfield[0].__geoloc.fl` in JavaScript. Whoof. (You wouldn't actually want to make it one big expression, but comments are short. :) )

Comment: Also, if it's interesting, here's a program using both type assertions and a type switch to walk through keys of a map: http://play.golang.org/p/_lxVlMe0i3 . It doesn't recurse as you'd need to in order to use a deep structure like yours, though.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing json like this can be very difficult. The default type of a parse is `map[string]interface{}`. The Problem arises when you have another complex data structure within the main json(like another list or object). The best way to go about decoding json is defining a struct to hold data. Not only will the values be of the correct type but you can extract the specific data you actually care about.

Your struct can look like this:

```
type Top struct {
    Topfield int `json:"topfield"`
}
```

which can be decoded like this:

```
a := []byte(`{"topfield": 123}`)
var data Top
json.Unmarshal(a, &data) //parse the json into data
```

now you can use regular struct operations to access your data like this:

```
value := data.Topfield
```

json which contains more complex data can also be easyli decoded. Perhaps you have a list in your data somewhere, you can use a struct like the following to extract it:

```
type Data struct {
    States []string `json:"states"`
    PopulationData []Country `json:"popdata"`
}

type Country struct {
    Id int `json:"id"`
    LastCensusPop int `json:"lcensuspopulation"`
    Gdp  float64 `json:"gdp"`
}
```

such a structure can not only parse list but also parse objects withing fields.

Comment: I'm aware that I can use a struct to decode the json and get the data I care about  but the client I'm using is returning me an interface so I'm wondering if I can "bind" that interface to a struct. The other option that I won't want to use is to encode again the interface into JSON and then decode it using a struct but that doesn't seem right.